How can i use "max" function in Google OR tools
Objective function is sigma(max (0, C_i\[i\] - d_i\[i\]))
my code is ..
Obj = sum(\[max(0, C_i\[i\] - d_j\[i\]) for i in range(1, job_num+1)\])
error is ...
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ortools/linear_solver/python/linear_solver_natural_api.py", line 169, in __gt__
raise ValueError('Operators "\<" and "\>" not supported with the linear solver')
ValueError: Operators "\<" and "\>" not supported with the linear solver

how can i use "max" function in python?
I try to express "max" in other ways.
for example, split it 2 equations.
T1 = sum(\[w_j\[i\] for i in range(1, job_num+1) if C_i\[i\] \<= d_j\[i\]\])
T2 = sum(\[w_j\[i\]\*(C_i\[i\] - d_j\[i\]) for i in range(1, job_num+1) if C_i\[i\] \> d_j\[i\]\])

and then minimize (T1+T2)

You cannot for 2 reasons:

max() is interpreted by python before call the add() method, and the result is very wrong for a mathematical model.
max() is not a linear formula. You can linearize it, but by nature, it does not work.

Some solver do support a max() operation in their API. But this is not consistent, and not exported at the linear solver method.
Note that CP-SAT supports add_max_equality(target, [expr1, ...]) with its native API.
